# load more data facing Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pdo

i got this load more data on my script which works ok on localhost and some other host but on my current host somehow i get the following error which i click the loadmore button

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost/getCat.php. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).  (unknown)

here is the js function that i use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Load more data
    $('.load-more').click(function(){
        var row = Number($('#row').val());
        var catid = Number($('#catid').val());
        var allcount = Number($('#all').val());
        row = row + <?php echo $records_per_page; ?>;
        if(row <= allcount){
           $("#row").val(row);
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo DIR; ?>getCat.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {row:row,catid:catid},
                beforeSend:function(){
                    $(".load-more").text("Loading...");
                },
                success: function(response){
                    // Setting little delay while displaying new content
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        // appending posts after last post with class="post"
                        $(".post:last").after(response).show().fadeIn("slow");
                        var rowno = row + <?php echo $records_per_page; ?>;
                        // checking row value is greater than allcount or not
                        if(rowno > allcount){

                            // Change the text and background
                             $(".load-more").text("No more.");
                             $('.load-more').css( 'pointer-events', 'none' );
                            $('.load-more').click(function(){return false;});
                            $('.load-more').css("background","#FB0925");
                        }else{
                            $(".load-more").text("Load more.");
                        }
                    }, 2000);
                }
            });
        }else{
            $('.load-more').text("Loading...");
            // Setting little delay while removing contents
            setTimeout(function() {
                // When row is greater than allcount then remove all class='post' element after 3 element
                $('.post:nth-child(3)').nextAll('.post').remove().fadeIn("slow");
                // Reset the value of row
                $("#row").val(0);
                // Change the text and background
                $('.load-more').text("Load more");
                $('.load-more').css("background","#333333");
            }, 2000);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you accidentally using this from the non-secure protocol, ie the error shows `https://` as the protocol, is the code you are trying loaded on `http://` which would cause a cross origin request

Comment: use `crossDomain: true` inside Ajax call

Comment: @KetanSolanki, that option is not doing what you think it is. That forces jQuery to make it so the request is sent as if it were cross domain even though it is actually just doing a request to the same domain. It does not magically make a server send out CORS headers.

Comment: @KetanSolanki that will not solve anything. Read the documentation for that option.

Comment: For more details - https://enable-cors.org/

Comment: @PatrickEvans the <?php echo DIR; ?> echos my domain url as https: // www.domain. com/